# How to expose docker container's ip and port to outside docker host without port mapping?

Tags: networking, port, docker

When i started two docker containers for a same web image on one docker host.

- two docker containers listened on the same port `5000`
- port `5000` of the two containers were mapped to different ports of docker host: `49155`, `49156`
- to access the two containers from outside docker host need to be by accessing the docker host ip and port `49155` or `49156`

Is there a solution to access a docker container from outside docker host by its ip and port, `x.x.x.x:5000`, without port mapping?

All docker containers on different dock hosts can access each other directly.

Comment: The question is unclear. Do docker containers to "be" on the same network adapter as the host? In that case, use `--net=host`. Or do you want to bind the port to not be random?

Answer (score 74):

You can accomplish this with IP aliasing on the host.

First, add a virtual interface on the host that has a different IP address than the primary interface. We'll call the primary interface `eth0` with IP `10.0.0.10`, and the virtual interface `eth0:1` with IP address `10.0.0.11`.

```
 ifconfig eth0:1 10.0.0.11 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

Now run the containers and map port 5000 to the corresponding interface. For example:

```
docker run -p 10.0.0.10:5000:5000 -name container1 <someimage> <somecommand>
docker run -p 10.0.0.11:5000:5000 -name container2 <someimage> <somecommand>
```

Now you can access each container on port 5000 using different IP addresses externally.

Comment: I am using boot2docker, I dont see eth0:1 avaliable for me in (boot2docker) mac, any further steps to get it working on mac ?

Comment: Try it like this `sudo ifconfig en1 inet w.x.y.z netmask 255.255.255.0 alias` where `en1` is the interface you want to add an alias for.

Comment: I tried , but it complaint  "Error response from daemon: Cannot start container XXXXX: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 172.16.1.99:80: bind: cannot assign requested address " , any clues?

Answer (score -7):

When creating a VM make sure that the following are selected under networking

```
Attached to:        Bridged NetworkManager
Adapter Type:       PCnet-Fast III (Am 79C973)
Promiscious Mode    Allow All
```

### RHEL 6.5 / Fedora 20

```
Install docker, libvrt
```

Make sure the following are done using root

```
# chkconfig NetworkManager off
# chkconfig network on  
# service NetworkManager stop
# service network start
```

Create file ifcfg-xxxxx in */etc/sysconfig/network-scripts*

```
DEVICE=xxxxx
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
DELAY=0
```

and append to `ifcfg-p2p1` / `ifcfg-eth0` at the end of the file `BRIDGE=xxxx`

### Restart the VM

run

```
brctl show
```

to make sure the bridged connected has an adapter either `p2p1` or `eth0` e.g.

```
# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
gsbr01          8000.080027595649       no              eth0
virbr0          8000.5254004c1564       yes             virbr0-nic
```

now before starting docker we have to **use our bridge** and not `docker0` to do that, run docker as `docker -d -b=gsbr01`

```
$ echo 'DOCKER_OPTS="-b=gsbr01"' >> /etc/sysconfig/docker
$ sudo service docker start
```

Check the result:

```
# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
gsbr01          8000.080027595649       no              eth0
                                                        veth5806f27
                                                        vethb3e33da
virbr0          8000.5254004c1564       yes             virbr0-nic

docker -d -b=gsbr01
```

Comment: How does this answer answers the question?