# Access to mongodb container from another host with container ip

Tags: mongodb, docker

I've created a mongodb container in docker with this command:

from host1:

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 mongo --bind_ip_all
```

I know host1.ip.

I find out container id with:

```
docker inspect <mongo_id>
```

For example container.ip = 172.17.0.2

From host2

if I run:

```
mongo --host: <host1.ip>:27017
```

it works

But if run

```
mongo --host: 172.17.0.2:27017
```

I get this error:

> MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
>   connecting to: mongodb://172.17.0.2:27017/
>   2018-06-20T13:54:17.111+0200 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: No route to host
>   2018-06-20T13:54:17.111+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 172.17.0.2:27017, connection attempt failed :
>   connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
>   @(connect):1:6
>   exception: connect failed

I'd know why it doesn't work and what i can do to manage that

Comment: Always remember to access your services or containers through hostnames, and never through IP's. As IP Address will change.

Comment: And 172 network is a private network.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Comment: I know 172 is private network. But I think  that if host1 and host2 are connected by wifi to same router i should not haveproblems. Isn't so?

Comment: Nope. I don't think it will be reachable.

Comment: What have i to do for set a Host nome for each container?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407434/how-to-configure-a-docker-container-to-be-reachable-by-container-ipport-from-ou