# How to expose docker container's ip and port to outside docker host without port mapping on TinyCore?

Tags: networking, docker

I want to expose docker host IP to outer host which like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036895/how-to-expose-docker-containers-ip-and-port-to-outside-docker-host-without-port).

There is a container running web service on port 3000 which is mapped to its host (a virtual box docker machine). How do I map this virtual network to my physic host except using Nginx?

(p.s. my network is pppoe)

Comment: What's wrong with port mapping? Or more to the point, do you just want to bind the container port to a host port so you can access the container service or do you have some other use case (in which case, please explain) ? Doing either task will be different for the docker-machine than regular docker on Linux, please also state your OS.