# Expose IP Address within a Docker container

Tags: docker, networking

I have a docker container which is running an instance of QEMU inside of it. This particular instance of QEMU is emulating a specific virtual device that self-assigns an IP address of 192.168.0.30.  The container's IP address is 172.17.0.2.  I would like to expose/forward all the traffic from the container to the QEMU instance such that when I visit the container's IP address; 172.17.0.2:80, I actually talk to 192.168.0.30:80 which is the QEMU instance inside of the container.  Any help would be really helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: You can attach container port to host port `-p 8080:8080`

Comment: So using -p exposes that container port to the host.  What I am attempting to do is expose an IP address within the container to the host.

Comment: Can you share the dockerfile used? Also can't the QEMU instance bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of a specific IP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to expose docker container's ip and port to outside docker host without port mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036895/how-to-expose-docker-containers-ip-and-port-to-outside-docker-host-without-port)

Comment: Different in that there is an emulated device inside of the docker container. Mapping the docker container does not map to the emulation running within the docker container. 

I think my answer will probably lay in making a iptables fwd rule inside of the container.