# Unable to access web app using docker's IP address but localhost is fine

Tags: docker, .net-core

I follow the tutorial at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-aspnet-core
and successfully run http://localhost:5000/WeatherForecast which return the web api data.

> [{"date":"2020-07-17T04:41:37.661625+00:00","temperatureC":41,"temperatureF":105,"summary":"Cool"},{"date":"2020-07-18T04:41:37.6633079+00:00","temperatureC":24,"temperatureF":75,"summary":"Sweltering"},{"date":"2020-07-19T04:41:37.6633109+00:00","temperatureC":49,"temperatureF":120,"summary":"Scorching"},{"date":"2020-07-20T04:41:37.6633112+00:00","temperatureC":-9,"temperatureF":16,"summary":"Hot"},{"date":"2020-07-21T04:41:37.6633114+00:00","temperatureC":40,"temperatureF":103,"summary":"Bracing"}]

My question is how do I access to docker's IP address instead of localhost? When I right click the Containers in VSCode and click `Inspect`, there is "IPAddress": "172.17.x.x". But when I go to http://172.17.0.2:5000/WeatherForecast, it returns with an error

```
This site can’t be reached
172.17.x.x took too long to respond.
```

Comment: `172.17.x.x` is the IP inside the docker environment. other images in the docker environment in the virtual network can reach it with that IP. From your host machine, you'll need to contact it with `localhost`

Comment: Check this answer, it might help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25041782/6332074
In case you're using Windows then run ipconfig instead of ifconfig.